# Booted Off Local Server - 302 error

Tags: moovweb

I'll start with the log that I am receiving below:

Dec.15.11.56-Rf: Incoming Request URL: /
Dec.15.11.56-Rf: SECURE GET Path: / From: mlocal.cldeals.com Rewritten: www.cldeals.com
Dec.15.11.56-Rf: Received 302 Found [text/html; charset=UTF-8] response for /
Dec.15.11.56-Rf: Sending 302 text/html; charset=UTF-8 response for /
Dec.15.11.56-Rf: Stats. Total: 0.52088702, Upstream: 0.48212701, Processing: 0.00105600, ProcessingOther: 0.04037500

Basically, when I go to mlocal.cldeals.com, it loads fine.  If I click on another page, say mlocal.cldeals.com/products, that loads fine as well. The issue seems to be when I go to the account page and try to switch back to the homepage, maybe some type of security issue? When I try to switch back to mlocal.cldeals.com, the home page, it boots me off and sends me to www.cldeals.com.  Is there something I can add to force this from not happening?  Additionally, is this just a local server issue that would go away when I launch it on Moovweb's server?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, this sounds like it could be a cookie issue perhaps?  Have you tried inspecting the request and responses that are made when you browse to the accounts page with both mlocal and the normal site?  I have an inclining that a cookie might not be set correctly, or perhaps you're missing a domain in your config.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the backend response to `https://www.cldeals.com` is a `302` to `http://www.cldeals.com:80/`. Not sure why that is the case (see note below *)

```
curl -v -o /dev/null https://www.cldeals.com
```

This response contains a hardcoded `Location` header and your project is passing along the response as is, which is why you are being booted off your local server.

Because the `Location` header value has a port specified, you'll need to modify your `config.json` to include this line in the mapping:

```
{
  "host_map": [
    "$.cldeals.com => www.cldeals.com",
    "$.cldeals.com => www.cldeals.com:80"
  ]
}
```

This way, the SDK knows to rewrite that specific host:port value... (By default all HTTP requests go through port 80, so that information isn't really necessary)

*This is might be bug in the backend implementation because once you log in, you should be in HTTPS mode until you log out. (I can see some pages with personal information being transmitted over plain HTTP)